# Convert string to decimal with precision and scale

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any helper method to convert a string to a decimal setting the format dynamically?

Something like this:

```
var myNumber = decimal.Parse(myString, precision, scale);
```

eg:

```
myString: "0109123456"
precision: 9
scale: 6
output: 109.123456
```

Original problem

I am reading values from a file that have a fixed length:

Sample line:

```
004574575434768743486765025448754546746485678696854745646874
```

For that I'm using FileHelpers, but each value has a different precision/scale:

```
Amount1 (pos0-pos16) - precision: 15, scale: 2
Amount1 (pos17-pos25) - precision: 7, scale: 3
```

FileHelpers gets me the value within the range that I determined but after that I need to convert it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for here - partly because you're asking for a decimal, but giving an example with `Convert.ToDouble`, and partly because you haven't given *any* examples of what you mean. Sample input and expected output - along with what you've tried so far - would make it easier to help you.

Comment: `decimal m = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(myString), 6); // 6 = x.xxxxxx`

Comment: sorry... there was a typo there... put convert instead of decimal.Parse

Comment: You could use [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) scale and precision properties are available here

Comment: I suspect you've encountered a different problem and think that defining a decimal with precision/scale is the solution. .NET's decimals *don't* have variable precision/scale. What are you trying to do? What is the original problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: BTW, the example text doesn't show *decimal parsing* at all. It converts one input (an integer literal) to an application-specific output. Just parse the text to an integer and divide it

Comment: Parsing file data is *very different* to parsing individual values. You could use a regular expression to extract the components of each line, then use them to construct the actual constructs you want.

Answer (score 4):

Quick example:

```
public static class stringExtension
{
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string s, int precision, int scale)
    {
        if (s.Length < precision)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return decimal
            .Parse(
            s.Substring(s.Length - precision)
            .Insert(precision - scale, ".")
            .ToString()
            ,
            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
            System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo
            );
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
        string s = "0109123456";
        decimal d = s.ToDecimal(9, 6); // returns 109.123456M
```

Comment: I use `var valor = "12345";` and `valor.ToDecimal(5, 2)` and I get **12345** value. `decimal.Parse("123.45")` returns  **12345** value. ***Culture issues*** about **"," and "."** like _DecimalSeparator and GroupSeparator_

Comment: @Kiquenet The length of the string is always known since this is an extension method. The problem you mentioned occurs because decimal separator is '.' in some cultures and ',' in others; however, the answer is now updated to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal` for this

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(SqlDecimal.Parse(yourString), 9, 6); // params: SqlDecimal n, int precision, int scale
```

Here's the [MSDN-link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.converttoprecscale(v=vs.110).aspx).

To get a `decimal`, you can use `SqlDecimal.Value` then.

Be careful if you use `ConvertToPrecScale` it throws a [SqlTruncateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqltruncateexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The exception that is thrown when you set a value into a
>   System.Data.SqlTypes

Comment: This would add a dependency to Sql Server Client and result in rather slow code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure it would but OP was asking if there is a way to convert from string to a decimal. No further information given so this is a solution that works

Comment: The exact question was about System.Decimal, which simply doesn't support scale. On the other hand, the question's *example* doesn't do decimal parsing at all. It tries to convert an integer string to a decimal